# Sending a file as binary stream with Axios POST request

Tags: http, promise, axios

I am trying to send a zip file to my backend which expects to get a binary stream. My code does work, but I'm afraid that I'm doing it wrong and that it might not be consistent.

```
function httpPostFile(inputPath: string, userName: string): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
        const input = fs.createReadStream(inputPath);
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
        };
        const params = ...
        const url = '/someUrl';
        return axios.post(url, input, {headers: headers, params: params});
    }
// then handle the promise
```

When I play with the numbers of the `highWaterMark` param of `fs.createReadStream` I get a 400 error more often for some values. Why? Do I have to take care of sending the data in chunks myself? Also, what happens in `axios.post` - how does it deal with the `highWaterMark` I set?

Comment: What is your `highWaterMark` param?

Comment: @ikhvjs I tried setting it to 8 * 1024 or 32 * 1024 for example. Default is 64 * 1024